# Fetch desde frontend hacia el backend en producción

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, fetch, despliegue

Mi proyecto consiste de un frontend en Reactjs y un backend en Nodejs. Las peticiones que hago desde el frontend hacia el backend de manera local funcionan bien, por ejemplo
 `fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {method: 'POST',headers: {"mode": 'no-cors',"Content-Type": "Application/json"}`

Pero cuando despliego el proyecto a producción, la ruta `http://localhost:3001/login` ya no va a ser funcional porque no estoy trabajando localmente. Mi duda es qué ruta debo indicar en el fetch cuando se está en producción.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Todo depende de como y donde lo hayas deployado, pero si lo has deployado todo en el mismo server, tiene que ser la misma url como cuando accedes a tu app de react. Ejmplo: frontend: https://mi-aplicacion-react.com,  backend: https://mi-aplicacion-react.com/login

Answer (score 1):

Usa **variables de entorno**

Podrías crear una variable de entorno llamada **REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL** y asignarle el valor **http://localhost:3001** en local y el valor **http://tu-dominio.com** en producción. Luego, podrías usar esa variable en tu código de React para hacer el fetch:

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/login`, {method: 'POST',headers: {"mode": 'no-cors',"Content-Type": "Application/json"}
```

Comment: Así lo estoy haciendo pero en producción no está funcionando.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. El problema estaba en el despliegue. Gracias.